# Angularjs ng-repeat filter display the whole array but style the filtered ones

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I need to apply a filter on ng-repeat that does not hide the no matching items but it will apply them a custom style for example different color.

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:query">
  <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

So when i apply the filter i need to see all the names but the filtered ones with different color.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to do what you want, and get rid of the `filter` part. Example:

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in friends">
  <li ng-class="friend.name.indexOf('Billy') >= 0 ? 'match' : 'no-match'">
    {{ friend.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can easily make the search part dynamic, but `query` would just be a simple string to test against:

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in friends">
  <li ng-class="friend.name.indexOf(query) >= 0 ? 'match' : 'no-match'">
    {{ friend.name }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is just one example. Without any other details about your query I can't completely answer your problem.